# Eloquent only updates the first record via ajax

Tags: laravel, sql-update, laravel-4, eloquent

i have a problem updating via ajax and eloquent.

I am making an .ajax in jquery :

```
           $('#button-acept').on("click",function(event) {
            event.preventDefault()
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ URL::to('/')}}/note_acept/{{$note->id}}',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data.message);
                    $('#alert-acepted').show();
                    $('.navbar-hide').hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

and the action of the url:

```
public function acept_note($id){

    $note = Noticia::find($id);
    $note->acept = true;
    $note->save();
    return Response::json(array('message'=>"The note has been acepted"));

}
```

The strange thing it's that when de note id it´s 1 it updates the acept field correctly, but if the note has any other id ( what it's obvious) it doesnt work.

I also tried with the query builder and it updates correcty but i also have a problem about giving points to the users.

This it's working:

```
DB::table('notes')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->update(array('acept' => true));
```

but when i try to use other eloquent update at the same function it doesn't work.

Comment: Just for debugging, try to `echo` the `$id` from the controller and see whether you get the correct `id` in your controller. Also, is `url: '{{ URL::to('/')}}/note_acept/{{$note->id}}'` right ? You can have a named route for the controller and use it;s name to generate the `url`, i,e. `Url::route('route_name')`.

Comment: Evrething works well, the url works but only when id = 1, when i echo the results form all the vars they work, what isn't working it's when i use de eloquent ti update and only at update because at creating it works fine.

Comment: I have the same problem, no answer, tried a lot of eloquent syntaxes, obviously a Laravel issue

Comment: This isn't a Laravel issue; that's not how this works. Add your rendered javascript for any ID above 1 and make sure you're actually receiving the method response. If you're not getting some sort of response you're doing something incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and its actually simply because you are using an id instead of a class. So when ajax runs, it expect only one element to be clicked. It will only care for the first row of your table.

Instead of using `#`, use `.`

Rename your `'#button-acept'` to `'.button-acept'`.. In your html, change your button to use `class=` instead of `id=`

I hope i'm not too late to answer this!
Cheers!